# FlipView onItemShow Event

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls, win-universal-app, flipview

I'm developing an app for windows 10 as following:

This is my Class

```
public class ImgurPost
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Uri thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Uri fullimage { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="flipItem" x:DataType="vm:ImgurPost">
   <Grid>
      <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}"/>         
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<FlipView ItemTemplate="{x:Bind flipItem}">
</FlipView>
```

The `FlipView.Itemsource` is connected with a IncrementalSource through the c# and works great, all items are shown.

But what I want is that when you flip to the next item I could **fire an event** to request the  **full image to be loaded and replace the thumbnail only on that active FlipViewItem** so when the app is loaded it is not downloading all full sized images in just one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event SelectionChanged to know when the user change the item and add your logic to change the image.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged

Update:

There are some ways to that.

1.-   you can use INotifyPropertyChanged in your model and change just the value of the property that contains with the url and is doing the binding with your image control inside of the item template

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269383.aspx

2.- you can use Item Template selector approach to change all the ItemTemplate depending of some value of your model .

https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/dynamically-choose-datatemplate-in-winrt/

the previous example it was for WinRT but is still valid for UWP apps

I think if you want to directly change the value of the source of the image it would be difficult but is possible using VisualTreeHelper

Comment: I'm trying to use it but the problem is that i can't find a way to add or change controls inside the Flipview's selectedItemcontainer because the Flipview.containerfromindex(FlipView.selecteindex) returns aways null no matter what.

Comment: I got it using the Template Selector approach Thanks